# Python - packing/unpacking by letters

Tags: python, string

I'm just starting to learn python and I have this exercise that's puzzling me:
Create a function that can pack or unpack a string of letters.
So aaabb would be packed a3b2 and vice versa.

For the packing part of the function, I wrote the following

```
def packer(s):
    if s.isalpha():        # Defines if unpacked

    stack = []

        for i in s:
            if s.count(i) > 1:
                if (i + str(s.count(i))) not in stack:
                    stack.append(i + str(s.count(i)))
            else:
                stack.append(i)

        print "".join(stack)

    else:
        print "Something's not quite right.."
        return False
packer("aaaaaaaaaaaabbbccccd")
```

This seems to work all proper. But the assignment says that
if the input has (for example) the letter a after b or c, then
it should later be unpacked into it's original form.
So  "aaabbkka" should become a3b2k2a, not a4b2k2.
I hence figured, that I cannot use the "count()" command, since
that counts all occurrences of the item in the whole string, correct?
What would be my options here then?

On to the unpacking - 
I've thought of the basics what my code needs to do -

1. between the " if s.isalpha():" and else, I should add an elif that
   checks whether or not the string has digits in it. (I figured this would be
   enough to determine whether it's the packed version or unpacked).
2. Create a for loop and inside of it an if sentence, which then checks for every element:

   2.1. If it has a number behind it > Return (or add to an empty stack) the number times the digit
   2.2. If it has no number following it > Return just the element.

Big question number 2 - how do I check whether it's a number or just another 
alphabetical element following an element in the list? I guess this must be done with
slicing, but those only take integers. Could this be achieved with the index command?

Also - if this is of any relevance - so far I've basically covered lists, strings, if and for
and I've been told this exercise is doable with just those (...so if you wouldn't mind keeping this really basic)

All help appreciated for the newbie enthusiast!

---

SOLVED:

```
def packer(s):
    if s.isalpha():        # Defines if unpacked
        groups= []
        last_char = None

        for c in s:
            if c == last_char:
                groups[-1].append(c)
            else:
                groups.append([c])
            last_char = c

        return ''.join('%s%s' % (g[0], len(g)>1 and len(g) or '') for g in groups)

    else:                   # Seems to be packed

        stack = ""

        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i].isalpha():
                if i+1 < len(s) and s[i+1].isdigit():
                    digit = s[i+1]
                    char = s[i]
                    i += 2

                    while i < len(s) and s[i].isdigit():
                        digit +=s[i]
                        i+=1
                    stack += char * int(digit)

                else:
                    stack+= s[i]
            else:
                ""
        return "".join(stack) 
print (packer("aaaaaaaaaaaabbbccccd"))
print (packer("a4b19am4nmba22"))
```

So this is my final code. Almost managed to pull it all off with just for loops and if statements.
In the end though I had to bring in the while loop to solve reading the multiple-digit numbers issue. I think I still managed to keep it simple enough. Thanks a ton millimoose and everyone else for chipping in!

Comment: For the packing, my algorithm would be: have a `start` and `end` index. Set `start` to 0, then increment `end` as long as the character at the `end` index is the same as the one at the `start` index. (Or until you reach the end of the string.) When the character changes, output the start character, and `end-start` (the length of the "run") of characters. Set `start` to `end`, repeat until `start` is greater than the string length.

Comment: (This uses the very common convention where, if specifying some sort of interval using indicex, the `start` index is *inclusive* and the `end` index is *exclusive*. So both of them point "before" a character.)

Comment: I'd handle the unpacking by checking if at any point you find a digit. If you do, just stop what you're doing, and call an unpacker function on the whole string. This takes advantage of the fact that for ambiguous strings (like `abc`) it doesn't matter what you do - neither packing nor unpacking will change them - this means it's safe to assume a string is unpacked until you find out otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward solution:
If a char is different, make a new group. Otherwise append it to the last group. Finally count all groups and join them.

```
def packer(s):
    groups = []
    last_char = None
    for c in s:
        if c == last_char:
            groups[-1].append(c)
        else:
            groups.append([c])
        last_char = c
    return ''.join('%s%s'%(g[0], len(g)) for g in groups)
```

---

Another approach is using `re`.

Regex `r'(.)\1+'` can match consecutive characters longer than 1. And with `re.sub` you can easily encode it:

```
regex = re.compile(r'(.)\1+')

def replacer(match):
    return match.group(1) + str(len(match.group(0)))

regex.sub(replacer, 'aaabbkka')
#=> 'a3b2k2a'
```

Comment: The first code works almost perfect. But in the case of "a" - it returns it packed a1, which is redundant to have the packed form longer than the original. I tried to implement an if statement to have it check the length of the occurring character, but I don't know of any way either than count and that doesn't really work.. Thoughts?

Comment: @Kano: You can replace `len(g)` with `len(g)>1 and len(g) or ''`

Answer (score 2):

I think You can use  `itertools.grouby' function

for example

```
import itertools
data = 'aaassaaasssddee'
groupped_data = ((c, len(list(g))) for c, g in itertools.groupby(data))
result = ''.join(c + (str(n) if n > 1 else '') for c, n in groupped_data)
```

of course one can make this code more readable using generator instead of generator statement

Comment: `len(list((i[1]))))` - that's a lot of parens.

Comment: I was alluding to the doubled paren around `i[1]` which is redundant. You could also destructure `i` with `for key, group in itertools.groupby(...)`

Comment: Also if the length of the group is `1` you should omit the length. You're looking for something like this: http://ideone.com/pUOX31

Answer (score 2):

This is an implementation of the algorithm I outlined in the comments:

```
from itertools import takewhile, count, islice, izip

def consume(items):
    from collections import deque
    deque(items, maxlen=0)

def ilen(items):
    result = count()
    consume(izip(items, result))
    return next(result)

def pack_or_unpack(data):
    start = 0
    result = []

    while start < len(data):
        if data[start].isdigit():
            # `data` is packed, bail
            return unpack(data)
        run = run_len(data, start)

        # append the character that might repeat
        result.append(data[start]) 

        if run > 1:
            # append the length of the run of characters
            result.append(str(run))

        start += run

    return ''.join(result)


def run_len(data, start):
    """Return the end index of the run of identical characters starting at 
    `start`"""
    return start + ilen(takewhile(lambda c: c == data[start], 
                                  islice(data, start, None)))

def unpack(data):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i].isdigit():
            # skip digits, we'll look for them below
            continue

        # packed character
        c = data[i]
        # number of repetitions
        n = 1
        if (i+1) < len(data) and data[i+1].isdigit():
            # if the next character is a digit, grab all the digits in the 
            # substring starting at i+1
            n = int(''.join(takewhile(str.isdigit, data[i+1:])))

        # append the repeated character
        result.append(c*n) # multiplying a string with a number repeats it
    return ''.join(result)

print pack_or_unpack('aaabbc')
print pack_or_unpack('a3b2c')
print pack_or_unpack('a10')
print pack_or_unpack('b5c5')
print pack_or_unpack('abc')
```

A regex-flavoured version of `unpack()` would be:

```
import re
UNPACK_RE = re.compile(r'(?P<char> [a-zA-Z]) (?P<count> \d+)?', re.VERBOSE)
def unpack_re(data):
    matches = UNPACK_RE.finditer(data)
    pairs = ((m.group('char'), m.group('count')) for m in matches)
    return ''.join(char * (int(count) if count else 1)
                   for char, count in pairs)
```

This code demonstrates the most straightforward (or "basic") approach of implementing that algorithm. It's not particularly elegant or idiomatic or necessarily efficient. (It would be if written in C, but Python has the caveats such as: indexing a string copies the character into a new string, and algorithms that seem to copy data excessively might be faster than trying to avoid this if the copying is done in C and the workaround was implemented with a Python loop.)

Comment: With the second input ("a3b2c") changing a3 to a31 - it only gives aaa still. Is it a whole new level to make it work with a 2-digit number?

Comment: @Kano Nope. Just involves replacing `int(data[i+1])` with something that takes all the consecutive digits in the string starting at the index `i+1`. This can be done using regexes but since you haven't covered them I'll get a version using itertools. (A whole lot of my loops could be.)

Comment: @Kano The code is now more `itertools`y. Also, more Schlemiel-the-paintery on accounts of skipping past the start of the string often. (Or substringing it a lot.) I'd say the efficient way of unpacking the string would be using a regex.